# Removing all traces of GNU java and openjdk and replacing with Sun JDK

Tags: linux, installation, java, fedora

I have installed latest Sun JDk. But when I do:

```
java -version
```

I still got OpenJDK version.
So I completely removed OpenJDK. But now when I do:

```
java -version
```

I get even older GNU java 1.5 something `libgcj`. So I completely removed that too but it was asking to remove bunch of dependent apps like OpenOffice.org Writer etc. Even though I need the writer, I let it go because I do not want ever to see the face of any GNU java on my linux. So everything related to GNU java is removed. Luckily I am able to start Eclipse and it works fine and start normally (apparently using the installed Sun JDK which is what I want). But now when I run

```
java -version
```

I get  bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

Now what I need to do so that when I open any terminal window and enter java -version
I should get Sun JDK version? Sun JDK is installed in /usr/java/jdk1.6.021. I also have symlinks: /usr/java/latest and /usr/java/defaults pointing to sun jdk.

As suggested in the answer, I tried the alternatives command but it did nothing. I type the --display, nothing is shown, and --config does nothing.

Comment: Why are you trying to get rid of GNU Java?

Comment: @Ben: I'm trying to do the same thing.  Primarily cause PhpStorm claims to be having issues with it.  I don't care whether it does or not, at this point -- what's the deal with having to rip out half the system to get rid of it?  What is this, Windows?

Answer (score 2):

on Debian 5.0.8 (lenny), i just used:

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to remove anything. On most Linux distros you can switch the java runtime environment. On fedora it is with `alternatives`.

To show which one is used:

```
alternatives --display java
```

To configure which one is used:

```
alternatives --config java
```